# Sqlalchemy order_by hybrid_property orders by something else

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So, I have a Product class and a User class. A User is the seller of a Product, and can have many products. The `Product.price` is the price without VAT, and each User have a flag in the User table `is_vat`, to state if the price showed externally shall have VAT added to it or not.

So I wanted to create a query which is ordered by price, and decided to create a hybrid_property (`show_price`) so that I would be able to order_by the price showed externally. The hybrid_property checks if the seller have the `is_vat` flag checked, and then calculates the outward showing price depending on whether VAT should be added or not.

**So, the problem is, the query results come out ordered on `Product.price`, instead of `Product.show_price`, and I don't understand what on earth I am doing wrong?**

This is the query I am using (Flask-sqlalchemy and old sqlalchemy syntax):

```
products_query = db.session.query(Product)
products = products_query.order_by(Product.show_price.desc()).all()
```

This is the Product class with the hybrid_property:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    
    @hybrid_property
    def show_price(self):
        is_vat = db.session.query(User.is_vat).filter(User.id == self.seller_id).first()[0]
        if is_vat == True:
            return (self.price * 1.25)
        if is_vat == False or is_vat == None:
            return (self.price * 1.0)
```

Edit:
Based on the response from @detlef I found out I had to create an expression for the hybrid_property. To first try to make a solution without the association_proxy, I made the following expression, which allows me to use Product.show_price in order_by. I believe the `expression` has to return a query object which calculates the value, not the value in itself.

```
@show_price.expression
def show_price(cls):
    return db.session.query(((db.func.coalesce(User.is_vat, False).cast(db.Integer) * 0.25) + 1) * cls.price).where(User.id == cls.seller_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Python code cannot be used directly in the SQL statement. A translation is necessary for the condition to work.

One way to accomplish your goal is to add the relationship to the seller and set an [`association_proxy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy) to the `is_vat` property. Then add an [`expression`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) for the `hybrid_property` that uses the [`case`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) statement. This is used to create the actual SQL statement for the query.

From then on, sorting should work by value depending on the condition.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy import case

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    seller = db.relationship('User')
    is_vat = association_proxy('seller', 'is_vat')

    @hybrid_property
    def show_price(self):
        return (self.price * 1.25) if self.is_vat else (self.price * 1.0)

    @show_price.expression
    def show_price(cls):
        return case(
            (cls.is_vat == True, cls.price * 1.25),
            else_=cls.price * 1.0
        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I did some experimentation based on your answer to see if it was possible to do without adding the association_proxy, because I am a bit worried about doing stuff that degrades performance and flexibility. I managed to create an expression function which I put in an edit to my initial post. I haven't done any benchmarking of performance. Do you have any opinions on association_proxy vs plain expression, or any other pros and cons?

Comment: I can understand your concerns about performance. As far as flexibility is concerned, it depends on the requirements. The `association_proxy` is helpful if you want to combine database columns independently of the platform. However, you know your database system and it may be that a direct request is processed more quickly. Unfortunately, my experience is not enough to give you advice on which option is better. However, I wish you much success with your project.

Comment: All right, understood. This wizardry of your was immensely helpful!